# Does iATS payment requires SEPA Direct debit for ACH to work?

Tags: payment-processor, iats

We are in the UK and would like to process direct debit from Civicrm. I found iATS payment processor can process ACH/DD.  Just wondering is processing UK DD a built in feature of iATS payment? Does it require any other plugins to work? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We did build UK Direct Debit [with the mandate - the entire workflow] into the iATS Payments Extension but it wasn't used much and we have not actively supported it recently. And SEPA works well and is widely adopted by lots of European CiviCRM Clients. One does not need to be exclusive -> you can processing CC with iATS Payments and use SEPA for DD for the time being.